# Checking the value of a bit in C

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

I am learning how to check the value of a bit. My textbook claims the following:

> Even if bit 1 in `flags` is set to 1, the other bit setting in `flags` can make the comparison untrue. Instead, you must first mask the other bits in `flags` so that you compare only bit 1 of `flags` with `MASK`:
>
> ```
> if ((flags & MASK) == MASK)
>   puts("Wow!");
> ```

I'm having trouble understanding this concept.

For instance, let `flags = 00001111` and `MASK = 10110110`.

Therefore, `flags & MASK = 00000110`.

If we now compared `MASK` and `00000110`, we would be comparing bits 2 and 3. However, isn't the goal to compare the value of a specific (single) bit?

I must be misunderstanding this. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c?rq=1

Comment: @FredrikPihl Thanks. They seem to use the shift operators, rather than equalities. In the context of the information from my textbook, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You usually don't compare against the mask after masking, but instead use the result as a boolean, as an enumerated value or what have you.

Comment: @IljaEverilä comparing against the mask checks whether every bit in the mask was set; using result as a boolean checks whether at least one of the bits in the mask was set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Condition `(flags & MASK) != 0` checks whether *any* of the `flags`'s bits specified by `MASK` are set to 1.
2. Condition `(flags & MASK) == MASK` checks whether *all* of the `flags`'s bits specified by `MASK` are set to 1.

Symmetrically

3. Condition `(flags & MASK) == 0` checks whether *all* of the `flags`'s bits specified by `MASK` are set to 0.
4. Condition `(flags & MASK) != MASK` checks whether *any* of the `flags`'s bits specified by `MASK` are set to 0.

Choose the one you need in each particular case.

If you need to check just a single bit (i.e. `MASK` contains only one bit set to 1), then conditons 1 and 2 are equivalent (and conditons 3 and 4 are equivalent as well).

It is not entirely clear from the text you quoted whether `MASK` can contain more than one bit set to 1.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly, checking a single bit can be done by using a bit mask that contains the specific bit to test. If the first bit (which corresponds to a value of two) is to be ckecked, one would use

```
result = flags & 00000010
```

and afterwards check `result`, which will be zero if the bit is not set and nonzero if the bit is set. More generalized, one could use

```
result = flags & (00000001 << i)
```

where `<<` denotes the shift operator to check the `i`-th bit.